# AsyncTask with ProgressDialog, dialog flashes by

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a AsyncTask called QueueTask that one of my Activities call. It should perform some operations while a progress dialog is shown. After the AsyncTask is done an intent is made and a new layout and activity comes to focus.

The issue is that the dialog flashes by real quick and then the intent is called. The dialog should stick, while the operations are carried out, which it does not. Why does it not stick?

Note:
doInBackground should take about 300 seconds to perform.

Call from activity:

```
QueueTask task = new QueueTask(date, roomNum, time, fieldInputUser, fieldInputCardNum);
task.execute();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatePickerActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

AsyncTask defined in the activity class:

```
public class QueueTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Library lib;
    private String date;
    private int room;
    private int time;
    private String user;
    private String id;

    public QueueTask(String date, int room, int time, String user, String id) {
        this.date = date;
        this.room = room;
        this.time = time;
        this.user = user;
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        lib = new Library();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ManageRoomActivity.this, "Queuing", "Queuing process");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int timer = 300;
        while(timer > 0) {
            if(lib.roomAvailable(date, room, time)) {
                lib.bookRoom(user, date, room, id, time);
                return null;
            }
            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            timer --;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

Fixed by puting:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ManageRoomActivity.this, DatePickerActivity.class);
        ManageRoomActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

into
    onPostExecute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `startActivity()` inside your `onPostExecute()` method.